# Call WCF Web api from another WCF Service

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have 2 WCF services.

The first WCF service is a Web API. The second WCF service is using the Web API from first WCF service.

I am using the following code to use the web api from the first service.

```
Dim httpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET"
            httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = True
            Dim httpWebRsp = TryCast(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

            Using strm_rdr As New StreamReader(httpWebRsp.GetResponseStream)
                responseData = strm_rdr.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
```

When I am trying to use the above code in the 2nd WCF service to call the web api from the first WCF service I am getting the error

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

The same code works fine when I am trying to call the web api from the first service from a console application.

I am not able to figure out why the error is coming when I call the web api from a WCF service.

Any help to resolve this error will be deeply appreciated.

I also see the following differences in fiddler when the web api request is sent from console application and wcfsvchost

**From Console**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 133

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Date: Sun, 23 Dec 2018 05:51:11 GMT

Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

**From wcfsvchost**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 0

Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Date: Sun, 23 Dec 2018 05:59:56 GMT
```

Not sure why server is Microsoft->> HTTPAPI/2.0 when request is sent from WCF service host.

Comment: I would like you could share the first WCF service details with me. In my opinion, there may be some authentication errors or http request format settings in this problem when you consuming the first WCF service on the second the service side.
Beside, please provide the console code consuming the first WCF service so that I could understand your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. I was debugging the issue a little further and found that the issue was because of the base address I had mentioned in host section for the second WCF service.  The address I mentioned there was http://localhost/Service and my first WCF service was also hosted in my local IIS. So when I launched the WCF service host for testing the second WCF service it was also being launched on the address http://localhost/Service and it was causing the bad request issue.  As soon I changed the address in the base section it started working fine.